# how to navigate from nested component to other component react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have a component in which on button click i render a component

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text> in Default component!</Text> 
    <Button title="add"
    onPress={this.handelSubmit} />
     {items.map((item, index) => (
         <Home key={index} data={index}  />))} 
 </View>
```

and my home component look like

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate("Calculator")}}>Semester {this.props.data +1}</Text>
  </View>
```

onPress event i want to navigate to other screen i.e 'Calculator.js' but i got an error 
[image: undefined is not an object] 
i am using react-navigation for navgation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to navigate from a component, you have to use your component like this:

```
<Home key={index} data={index} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```